# Excel VBA Saveas function corrupting file

Tags: excel, save, save-as, vba

When I try to save my file with the ActiveWorkbook.Save function. The file get's corrupted and i cannot use it anymore.

I already tried the ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs function, but the result is the same. Below the example. I have added the 2 other functions used on the bottom.

```
Sub Publish_WB()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim cell As Range
Dim CurrentPath, OriginalFname, NewFname, FName As String

If CheckPublished() Then
    MsgBox ("Published version, feature not available ...")
    Exit Sub
End If

NoUpdate
PublishInProgress = True

'Save the Current Workbook
OriginalFname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

'Store the current path
CurrentPath = CurDir

'Change the path to the same of the current sheet
SetCurrentDirectory ActiveWorkbook.Path

NewFname = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "_published.xlsm")

FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", InitialFileName:=NewFname, Title:="Save Published Version as")
If FName <> "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FName, 52
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (OriginalFname)
Else
    'user has cancelled
    GoTo einde
End If
```

function CheckPublished()

```
Function CheckPublished() As Boolean

If Range("Quoting_Tool_Published").Value = True Then
    CheckPublished = True
Else
    CheckPublished = False
End If
End Function
```

and the NoUpdate :

```
Sub NoUpdate()
If NoUpdateNested = 0 Then
    CurrentCalculationMode = Application.Calculation 'store previous mode
End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.Cursor = xlWait


    NoUpdateNested = NoUpdateNested + 1
   ' Debug.Print "NoUpdate, Noupdatenested = " & NoUpdateNested

End Sub
```

if we jump to einde, I call the following function :

```
Sub UpdateAgain()

NoUpdateNested = NoUpdateNested - 1

If NoUpdateNested < 1 Then
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'let all sheets be calculated again first
    Application.Calculation = CurrentCalculationMode 'set to previous mode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
Else
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'recalculate sheets, but keep the rest from updating
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End If

'Debug.Print "UpdateAgain, Noupdatenested = " & NoUpdateNested

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `GoTo einde` and I don't think you're adding a '.xlsm' to your file so it saves it without an extension

Comment: Hi Tom, the Goto Einde calls the last function above (UpdateAgain), the function thisworkbook.name get's the name including the extension

Comment: Also if the workbook hasn't been saved before this is run then it will try to save `\Book1` which will understandably fall over

Comment: How is the file corrupted? Can you show us the error message? Is the file saved with an extension after using `SaveCopyAs`

Comment: The file is already saved and is names QT2.0.16_projectname.xlsm to start with, The file QT2.0.16_projectname_published.xlsm is also created, but my original file is corrupted

Comment: The Error I get is : We found a problem with some content in 'QT2.0.16_projectname.xlsm' do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes. Also the QT2.0.16_projectname_published.xlsm file has the same error. If I use the Save or Save as command manually there is not problem. If i make a Sub with only ActiveWorkbook.Save and then exit sub, it also gives the same error

Comment: If you try `SaveCopyAs`on your code, the `OriginalFname`has no extension, right?
Also, shouln't the `SaveAs` be like `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName`? I have no idea what that 52 means, so could you enlighten me on that?

Comment: @Moacir 52 is the filetype `xlsx`

Comment: `PublishInProgress = True

'Save the Current Workbook
OriginalFname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name` Here you save the file without a file extension, add that to it.

Comment: `NewFname = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "_published.xlsm")` also this probably won't work, as there is no .xlsm in thisworkbook.name. Go to the immediate window and type in `msgbox(thisworkbook.name)` and see for yourself.

Comment: The functions does work and the thisworkbook.name functions included the .xlsm I checked that with a debugger.

Comment: I solved the problem by using a name for the workbook. I used [code]'dim wb as workbook' and then later 'wb.save' and 'wb.saveas' and both files are okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a name for the workbook than rather activeworkbook I was able to solve the problem; the rest of the code is the same, so the rest was not causing any issues.

```
Sub Publish_WB()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb as Workbook


Dim cell As Range
Dim CurrentPath, OriginalFname, NewFname, FName As String

If CheckPublished() Then
    MsgBox ("Published version, feature not available ...")
    Exit Sub
End If

NoUpdate
PublishInProgress = True

'Save the Current Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Save

'Store the current path
CurrentPath = CurDir

'Change the path to the same of the current sheet
SetCurrentDirectory ActiveWorkbook.Path

NewFname = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "_published.xlsm")

FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", InitialFileName:=NewFname, Title:="Save Published Version as")
If FName <> "" Then
    wb.SaveAs FName, 52
Else
    'user has cancelled
    GoTo einde
End If
```